# Placing text and image on the same row in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am building a personal website using Django and I have one app in it - home. On my home page I want to place an image and text on the same row (side by side). I have tried several ways to do this using Bootstrap but none of them seem to work. 
Below is my code and the text appears right below the image instead of being NEXT to the image.

home's template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Boostrap -->
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/basic.css' %}">

  <!-- Font-Awesome (Icons) -->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8e86dbd2db.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pranav Gupta</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      {% url 'home:index' as index %}
      {% url 'home:portfolio' as portfolio %}
      {% url 'home:blog' as blog %}
      {% url 'home:contact' as contact %}
      <li {% if request.path == index %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'home:index' %}">Home</a></li>
      <li {% if request.path == portfolio %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'home:portfolio' %}">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li {% if request.path == blog %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'home:blog' %}">Blog</a></li>
      <li {% if request.path == contact %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'home:contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}

  {% block two %}
  {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

home's index.html

```
{% extends "home/template.html" %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    {% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{% static "home/img/me.jpg" %}" alt="Me" width="30%" /> 
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    {% block two %}
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any markup outside `block` tags in your child (index.html) template as this will not get rendered. Try moving the row and column logic to your base template:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       {% block two %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

That said, there are easier ways to display text next to images, but I suspect this is a general problem with your site layout that you would want to have fixed on other pages as well.